# ımu position on robot

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ı want use to imu on my robot. But ı cant understan how do I place my imu on my roboy. so imu see to which direction ?

my imu : http://wiki.ros.org/um7

[http://i.imgur.com/MdeN9er.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/MdeN9er.jpg)

the feed direction robot will be  imu's x direction ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216539/%C4%B1mu-position-on-robot/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it looks like the code takes this into account

Source file is here https://github.com/ros-drivers/um7/blob/indigo-devel/src/main.cpp

```
// IMU outputs [w,x,y,z], convert to [x,y,z,w] & transform to ROS axes
    imu_msg.orientation.x =  r.quat.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.orientation.y = -r.quat.get_scaled(2);
    imu_msg.orientation.z = -r.quat.get_scaled(3);
    imu_msg.orientation.w = r.quat.get_scaled(0);
```

so looks like you put it with the x pointing forwards from the robot, fixing the device so the it looks the right way up from its packaging - the code flips the values round to match right hand rule.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-08-26**:
Thanks @nickw. you think is it correct in this way : ?????
[http://i.imgur.com/UweLTQu.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/UweLTQu.jpg)

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-08-27**:
@nickw ı am not sure  ???

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-08-27**:
I would expect that to be correct - the test now is to run the node and check the values you get make sense and change in the way you would expect to if you change the robots orientation.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-08-28**:
yes you are right...